# PHP / Javascript AES 128 CFB Encryption / Decryption CryptoJS OpenSSL

Tags: javascript, php, encryption

Working Decryption in PHP

```php
function decrypt($encryptedText){
    $key = "1234567890123456";
    $decrypted = openssl_decrypt(substr(base64_decode($encryptedText), 16), "AES-128-CFB", $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, substr(base64_decode($encryptedText), 0, 16));
    return $decrypted;
}
$encryptedText = "1EwMDT20BELrEixvrSGswDC4GZIn5BWGor6MP6ERi9Ux";
echo decrypt($encryptedText);
```

Will output "Decrypted Message"

I'm trying to replicate it in Javascript

```js
var key = '1234567890123456';
var base64data = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse("1EwMDT20BELrEixvrSGswDC4GZIn5BWGor6MP6ERi9Ux");
var encrypted = new CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.init(base64data.words.slice(4));
var iv = new CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.init(base64data.words.slice(0, 4));
var cipher = CryptoJS.lib.CipherParams.create({ ciphertext: encrypted });
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(cipher, CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key), {iv: iv, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CFB});
console.log("Decrypted: "+decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
```

I get an empty response, any help would be appreciated as to where I've gone wrong.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[CFB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_feedback_(CFB)) is a stream cipher mode, i.e. does not use padding.

In a mode with padding, the ciphertext always has a length that corresponds to an integer multiple of the block size, i.e. 16 bytes for AES. This means that the ciphertext always consists of *complete* `WordArray`s (a `WordArray` is 4 bytes in size).

In a mode without padding, such as CFB, the ciphertext has the same length as the plaintext, so that the last `WordArray` *is generally not completely* part of the ciphertext.
For instance, the message *Decrypted Message* has a length of 17 bytes, i.e. consists of 5 `WordArray`s, the last of which has only *one* significant byte.
Therefore the number of significant bytes: `base64data.sigBytes - 16`, must be specified for `encrypted` (the subtraction of 16 is necessary because `base64data` also contains the IV).

Furthermore, the padding must be *explicitly* disabled.

With these two changes, the decryption is successful:

```js
var key = '1234567890123456';
var base64data = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse("1EwMDT20BELrEixvrSGswDC4GZIn5BWGor6MP6ERi9Ux");
var encrypted = new CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.init(base64data.words.slice(4), base64data.sigBytes - 16); // consider significant bytes
var iv = new CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.init(base64data.words.slice(0, 4));
var cipher = CryptoJS.lib.CipherParams.create({ ciphertext: encrypted });
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(cipher, CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key), {iv: iv, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CFB, padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding}); // disable padding
document.getElementById("pt").innerHTML = "Decrypted: " + decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.0.0/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
<p style="font-family:'Courier New', monospace;" id="pt"></p>
```

By the way, there are different variants of CFB. Here, both codes use full block CFB (CFB128).